# Bulma fixed bottom navbar scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, bulma

I'm having a problem with this ""fixed"" bottom navbar. 
It is realized with bulma v0.8.0 and it I want it to always be visible in the same way (with or without scrolling).
Below code of the bottom navbar:

```
<html lang="en" class="has-navbar-fixed-bottom">
[...]
<nav id="navbar-bottom" class="navbar is-fixed-bottom is-hidden-tablet" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <div class="columns flex-center">
      <div class="column socialtext">Share</div>
      [...]
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And the results is like:

[image: Navbar1]

When I try to scroll down, the navbar show "correctly".
I have tried with some js library but still does not work.
Could I have some tips about that?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide some minimal, runnable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Solved. The issue is related to the "tile" element.